# SVG xml to image

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have an svg code that I want to convert as `<img>`. Any idea howto do this?

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="58" height="308">
    <foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">
        <h3 style="padding:0;margin:0;text-align:center;font-size:16px;">Legend</h3>
        <ul style="position: relative; font-size: 12px; list-style-type: none; margin-left: 20px; min-width: 15px; ">
            <li style="position:absolute;top:17.5px">1</li>
            <li style="position:absolute;top:43.5px">0</li>
            <li style="position:absolute;top:66.5px">0</li>
            <li style="position:absolute;top:90.5px">0</li>
            <li style="position:absolute;top:113.5px">0</li>
            <li style="position:absolute;top:136.5px">0</li>
            <li style="position:absolute;top:159.5px">0</li>
            <li style="position:absolute;top:183.5px">0</li>
            <li style="position:absolute;top:206.5px">0</li>
            <li style="position:absolute;top:229.5px">0</li>
            <li style="position:absolute;top:253.5px">0</li>
        </ul>
        <div style="position: relative; display: block; width: 15px; height: 256px; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-color: black; background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAA8AAAEACAYAAABs9ywrAAAC7klEQVRoQ+3bW0iUQRTA8bOJJSammGilYpKJiWJuJJHRIhUaRZikoGGBRSxFiVgRXTYqugihEYmVhN2ITUS8sIgspYaUlImgJVJJSmgXzCgJw/ySEh/CxTj/p2CHGeZlfhw4zPcxDHNMItI4OSamP832u8/cTBNLTk6OqdWGSYyZqcj02IPg2QR7EexNsA/B8wj2JziA4ECCgwheSHAIwWEEhxMcQXAkwVEERxMcQ3AcwfEEJxC8guCVBK8ieDXBawheS3AywesI3kBwCsEbCd5E8BaC0whOJ3gbwZkEZxG8neAcgncSnEvwboL3EGwleC/B+wnOIzif4AKCDxN8hOCjBB8HeNxG8CmCzxB8luDzBBcSfJHgIoIvEXyZ4BKCSwm+RnAZwTcILif4NsF3Cb5HsJ3gCoIrCa4iuBpgo45gB8H1BDcQ7CT4AcGNBDcT3ELwY4JbCX5KcBvB7QR3ENxJ8AuCuwnuIfg1wb0EvyW4n+B3BA8S/IHgTwQPETxM8FeCRwj+TvAowWMEjwP8wwD4C8GDBPcS/JLg5wS3EOwkuJbg+wTfJLiU4GKCzxF8guCDBO8jOJfgLILTCE4l2EJwIsFmw1P/PMJs+BG8iOClBC8nOIngFILTCc4h2EpwAcE2ggsJvkJwOcEVBDsIbiK4jeBugvsJHiJ4FOAxA+ARgj8T/J7gPoJfEdxFcDvBrQQ3E+wk2EFwFcF2gm8RXEZwCcFFBF8g+DTBxwg+RPABgq0E7yJ4B8HZBGcQvJXgzQSnEryeYAvBSQQnEmwmOI7gZQRHEryY4FCCgwmeT7AfwXMJnkPwLIAT5Kf+yBwv4LAeK9/0kWNkWI+j5aMeR8mAHi+RPj2OkDd6HC49ehwmXXocIh16vECe6XGQPNHjQHmkxwHyUI/9pUGPfQXcVvhIjT6yt1TqsZfY9dhT7uixh4CLJZNc10cWuerGLgoJp60ddCfMddmlO2FTuXF/Va62yX+8SSx/lzD/68/gFwryaXEkBvE8AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC); "></div>
    </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019462/how-to-convert-svg-files-to-other-image-formats

Comment: Can't you just add your SVG file as a `src` on the `<img>`?

Comment: You can convert the SVG XML to an image base 64, then use the base 64 as the `src` of the `<img>` element.

Answer (score -1):

This kind of transformation cannot be performed in XML or HTML.  The problem is not the markup code, but that you need to convert one kind of media to another kind.  Furthermore, you are changing an text based format to a binary (BLOB) based format.  You will need to save down the svg code into an XML compatible SVG file and then use some online image conversion application like:

- http://www.online-utility.org/image_converter.jsp
- http://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-svg
- http://www.fileformat.info/convert/image/svg2raster.htm